# How to upload multiple images in laravel with proper validation and with filename error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to upload multiple images in Laravel with the error showing the filename into a [Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features) file. Like I want to upload, say, four files. Two of them are images and the other two are PDF files, so it should stop me to do it, as I want just images to get uploaded and will also show me the two PDF files' name which are not allowed. But I do get:

```
The uploads.0 must be an image.
The uploads.0 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg.


The uploads.2 must be an image.
The uploads.2 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg.
```

So I want that the user must know that into which file they are making the mistake as there is the possibility of uploading more than 20 files, so if I can print the filename they can easily identify where is the problem. Also, I cannot get this error to be printed down the input; I got this error by using this code into my Blade file,

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<ul>

  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
     <li>{{ $error }}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
</div>
@endif
```

So I want that the validation should work with the filename and it should be shown below the input file as into my other input fields showing.

Into my other input fields I have shown the errors with this for all errors

```
@if($errors->has('shipping_code'))
<div class="error text-danger fs-6 fw-400">{{ $errors->first('shipping_code') }}</div>
@endif
```

Into my controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[

        'shipping_code' => 'required|string',
        'customer_name' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'shipper_name' => 'nullable|exists:users,id',
        'shipping_details' => 'nullable|string',
        'pickup_date' => 'required|date',
        'delivery_date' => 'nullable|date',
        'driver_name' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'driver_fee' => 'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
        'transaction_fee' => 'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
        'remarks' => 'nullable|string',
        'status' => 'required|in:0,1,2,3',
        'uploads' => 'required',
        'uploads.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return redirect()->route('shipping.create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
    else{

        DB::transaction(function () use($request) {

            $exPd = explode(',',$request->driver_name);
            $driver_id = $exPd[0];

            $shipping = new Shipping();
            $shipping->shipping_code = $request->shipping_code;
            $shipping->customer_id = $request->customer_name;
            $shipping->shipper_id = $request->shipper_name;
            $shipping->driver_id = $driver_id;
            $shipping->shipping_details = $request->shipping_details;
            $shipping->pickup_date = convertDateToDB($request->pickup_date);
            $shipping->delivery_date = convertDateToDB($request->delivery_date);
            $shipping->driver_fee = $request->driver_fee;
            $shipping->transaction_amount = $request->transaction_fee;
            $shipping->remarks = $request->remarks;
            $shipping->status = $request->status;
            $shipping->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $shipping->created_by = Auth::user()->id;

            $shipping->save();

            if($request->hasfile('uploads')) {
                foreach($request->file('uploads') as $file)
                {
                    $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$file->extension();
                    $filePath = public_path('/uploads/shipping_transaction_images/');
                    $img = Image::make($file->path());
                    $img->resize(110, 110, function ($const) {
                        $const->aspectRatio();
                    })->save($filePath.$input['imagename']);
                    $imgData[] = $input['imagename'];
                    $fileModal = new ShippingImage();
                    $fileModal->shipping_id = $shipping->id;
                    $fileModal->image_type = 'pickup';
                    $fileModal->image_file = $input['imagename'];
                    $fileModal->save();
                }
            }
        });

        return redirect()->route('shippings.index')
                            ->with('success','Shipping Transaction Created Successfully');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your validation like this:

```
$messages = [];
if($request->hasfile('uploads')){
    // dd($request->file('uploads'));
    foreach ($request->file('uploads') as $key => $file) {
        $messages['uploads.'.$key.'.image'] = 'The ' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be an image.';
       $messages['uploads.' . $key . '.mimes'] = 'The ' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be a file of type: :values.';
    }

}
$request->validate([   
    'shipping_code' => 'required|string',
    'customer_name' => 'required|exists:users,id',
    'shipper_name' => 'nullable|exists:users,id',
    'shipping_details' => 'nullable|string',
    'pickup_date' => 'required|date',
    'delivery_date' => 'nullable|date',
    'driver_name' => 'required|exists:users,id',
    'driver_fee' => 'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
    'transaction_fee' => 'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
    'remarks' => 'nullable|string',
     'status' => 'required|in:0,1,2,3',
    'uploads' => 'required|array',
    'uploads.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
], $messages);
```

You can fetch errors for other fields, like the way you have used:

```
@if($errors->has('shipping_code'))
<div class="error text-danger fs-6 fw-400">{{ $errors->first('shipping_code') }}</div>
@endif
```

But for uploads you can use.

For getting if no file selected:

```
@if ($errors->has('uploads'))
    <div class="help-block has-error">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('uploads') }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

If multiple selected files have an error:

```
@if($errors->has('uploads.*'))

    @foreach ($errors->get('uploads.*') as $message)
        @foreach ( $message as $value)
            <div class="help-block has-error">{{ $value }}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Also it will not harm your `DB::transaction`. See *[Get filename of failed multiple uploaded files in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73654202/get-filename-of-failed-multiple-uploaded-files-in-laravel/73658905#73658905)*.

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"But for uploads you can use"*