# Get filename of failed multiple uploaded files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

With reference to the previously answered Stack Overflow question that is being asked at *[Get filename of failed uploaded file in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628951/get-filename-of-failed-uploaded-file-in-laravel-5-4)*, I have implemented the same, but I am not getting the failed uploaded filename. Where am I doing wrong?

```
$validationArray = [];
$messages = [];
if($request->hasfile('uploads')){
    // dd($request->file('uploads'));
    foreach ($request->file('uploads') as $key => $file) {
        $validationArray['uploads.'.$key.'.image'] = 'The ' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be an image.';
    }
    $messages = [
        $validationArray
    ];
}
$request->validate([
    // 'customer_name' => 'required|exists:users,id',
    'uploads' => 'required|array',
    'uploads.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
], $messages);
```

With this, I am getting the error as:

```
The uploads.0 must be an image.
The uploads.0 must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png.
```

I want to have the file name in place of the `uploads.0`.

Comment: A question... are you using Laravel 8 or 5.4? You mentioned a question from 5.4, but it has Laravel 8 tag.

Comment: I am using laravel 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the same question asked at *[Get filenames of failed multiple uploaded files in Laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-filename-of-failed-multiple-uploaded-files-in-laravel)*.

You can do this to your validation:

```
$messages = [];
if($request->hasfile('uploads')) {
    // dd($request->file('uploads'));
    foreach ($request->file('uploads') as $key => $file) {
        $messages['uploads.' . $key . '.image'] = 'The ' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be an image.';
        $messages['uploads.' . $key . '.mimes'] = 'The ' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be a file of type: :values.';
    }
}

$request->validate([
    // 'customer_name' => 'required|exists:users,id',
    'uploads' => 'required|array',
    'uploads.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
], $messages);
```

And for fetching errors into your blade.

For getting if no file selected

```
@if ($errors->has('uploads'))
    <div class="help-block has-error">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('uploads') }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

If multiple selected files have an error

```
@if($errors->has('uploads.*'))

    @foreach ($errors->get('uploads.*') as $message)
        @foreach ($message as $value)
            <div class="help-block has-error">{{ $value }}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine, but try this. It should work.

```
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that those methods are not recomended by laravel for production mode, use `$file->hashName()` and `$file->extension()`. Thats the part of the docs im referring to: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#other-uploaded-file-information)

Comment: Its not working i have checked